# How do I apply a style to the ListViewItems in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styles, listviewitem

First of all, I am new to WPF.

---

I have this style ready for my items:

```
    <Style x:Key="lvItemHover" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

How do I give this style to the items in my `ListView`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this

```
     <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                  </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item3</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have many options

- Remove the `x:Key="lvItemHover"`
  from your style and it will get
  applied to all your ListViewItems
- Apply the style to each
  ListViewItem like

  `<ListViewItem
  Style="{StaticResource
  lvItemHover}">Item1</ListViewItem>`
- Put your style inside the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` as in the above post

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest way to define ListViewItem style from static resource:

```html
    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lvItemHover}">
    </ListView>
```